# get the list of all message types in python

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to get the list of all ros messages types in python? I'm looking for an equivalent of the command line tool rosmsg in python, something like 'rosmsg list'. I haven't found it in rospy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255978/get-the-list-of-all-message-types-in-python/) by [patson](https://answers.ros.org/users/29536/patson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-03-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`rosmsg` *is* python (as are many of the command line tools: [ros_comm/tools](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/tree/lunar-devel/tools)).

---

Originally posted by [kramer](https://answers.ros.org/users/2050/kramer/) with karma: 1470 on 2017-03-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0